# Css Skew to create a picture frame

Tags: html, css, image, frame, skew

I am trying to skew a div on each side to mimic a picture frame angle using CSS, I cannot figure out how to skew each end separately and retain a background image.

Comment: Can you show us an example?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vkpsja8r/

Comment: The code in this jfiddle gives you a rough idea, basically my problem also lies in the fact that the angle goes past the div area as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated** Add two more div that will be a trick

```
 <div class="container">
       <div class="topFrame"> </div>
       <div class="leftFrame"></div>
       <div class="imgContainer">IMG GOES HERE</div>
       <div class="rightFrame"></div>
       <div class="botFrame"></div>
       <div class="leftTriangle"></div> <!--New Div left lower triangle-->
       <div class="rightTriangle"></div> <!--New Div right lower triangle-->
 </div>
```

Don't use skew for topFrame and bottomFrame

```
.botFrame:after { 
    display:block;
    content: ' '; 
    background: #444; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}  
.topFrame:after { 
    display:block;
    content: ' '; 
    background: #888;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

First set `overflow` to `hidden` for container and make these changes

```
.container{
     overflow: hidden;
 }

.leftFrame{
     background: #888;
}
.leftFrame:after {
    transform: skew(0deg, 45deg);
}
.leftTriangle{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 50px 50px 0 0;
    border-color: #131213 transparent transparent transparent;
}
.rightTriangle{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 50px 50px 0;
    border-color: transparent #222222 transparent transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Check Out
**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UZ6HL/105/)**

User Below CSS to create skew:

```
.menu-item{
    transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
     background-color:#1a0000;
    color:white;
}

.inner{
    transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg);
}
```